Jacobian Zero Point Between Equal Function Values

Assume that $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a convex region, and the functions $u = u(x, y), v = v(x, y)$ are defined on the region $D$, continuous and with continuous first-order partial derivatives. Let $W(P) = (u(x, y), v(x, y))$ be a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.
Prove: For any two distinct points $P_1(x_1, y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2, y_2)$ in $D$, if $W(P_1) = W(P_2)$, where $W(P_i) = (u(x_i, y_i), v(x_i, y_i))$ for $i = 1, 2$, then there must exist a point $P_\xi$ between $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that the Jacobian determinant
$$
\frac{\partial(u, v)}{\partial(x, y)}\Bigg|_{P_\xi} = 0.
$$

Since $D$ is a convex region, the line segment with endpoints $P_1$ and $P_2$ lies in $D$. Any point on the line segment can be represented by:
$$
P_t\left( x_1 + t(x_2 - x_1), y_1 + t(y_2 - y_1) \right), \ t \in [0, 1]
$$
Let
$$
F(t) =  W(P_t) 
$$
Then
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}=\left( u_{x}(x_{2}-x_{1})+u_{y}(y_{2}-y_{1}),v_{x}(x_{2}-x_{1})+v_{y}(y_{2}-y_{1}) \right) 
$$
The partial derivative is evaluated at the point$\left( x_{1}+t(x_2-x_{1}),y_{1}+t(y_{2}-y_{1}) \right)$
Applying the Lagrange Mean Value Theorem to the two components of $F(t)$, if the mean value is taken at the same point, then the proposition holds. However, the mean value of these two components is not necessarily taken at the same point. How can this problem be solved?
